# Can you use personification and then refer to the inanimate thing as a part of your body?

Tags: creative-writing, figures-of-speech

Can you use personification and then refer to the inanimate thing as a part of your body?

For example:

> The mournful hills, full of violent rivers, cried my lost uncle.

It sounds like an odd thing to do, so I was wondering if I could use hills to refer to my face or something along that line.

Comment: That sentence isn't talking about a part of *your* body; it seems to be talking about violent rivers being at least partly formed from *your uncle's* body, and being cried by the hills. But it's all metaphorical, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: First. What do you mean for this to say?